The pointer of MapViewOfFile throw OverflowException exception when switch to .NET Core
I'm trying to run this project DbMon.NET - A simple .NET OutputDebugString capturer in .NET Core (.NET 5.0).
It runs fine in .NET 4.7.2, but when I switch to .NET 5, I keep getting an exception

System.OverflowException: Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow.

thrown by System.IntPtr.ToInt32()
Here are the details:

Step 1: Download DbMon.NET source code.

Step 2: Add the file DebugMonitor.cs to my .NET 5.0 console project.

Step 3: I execute DebugMonitor in the file Program.cs like this:
      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
          DebugMonitor.OnOutputDebugString += new OnOutputDebugStringHandler(PrintDebugString);
          DebugMonitor.Start();

          Console.Read();
          DebugMonitor.Stop();
      }

      private static void PrintDebugString(int id, string szMsg)
          => Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", id, szMsg);


Step 4: Run the project. The code always throw exception at m_SharedMem.ToInt32() in the file DebugMonitor.cs. the value of m_SharedMem is m_SharedMem = MapViewOfFile(m_SharedFile, SECTION_MAP_READ, 0, 0, 512);.


The exception is:

System.OverflowException: Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow

In step 2, if I use .NET 4.7.2 instead of .NET 5.0, I won't get the exception. So I guess .NET 5.0 might require to setup some security rule or something, I have this this question (MemoryMappedFile low-integrity .Net 5) but haven't figured out how to fix this DbMon.Net in .NET 5.0.

Sounds like the successful one is running as 32 bit, and the failing one is running as 64 bit.

Thank to @IInspectable 's comment. I got the answer.
It's because .NET Core (.Net 5.0) favors 64-bit in AnyCPU, and .NET Framework (.Net 4.7.2) favors 32-bit.
You can check it when run this code in each project Console.WriteLine("Int Size = {0}", IntPtr.Size);: .Net Framework will give Int Size = 4 (32 bit), .Net core will give Int Size = 8 (64 bit).
So the solution is just remove .ToInt32() entirely, the final code should update like this:
Change the old code:
IntPtr pString = new IntPtr(
                    m_SharedMem.ToInt32() + Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(int))
                ); //Old code, bug here!

to the new code:
IntPtr pString = m_SharedMem + Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(int));


I copied all the classes into a fresh .net 8 solution and replaced MainMenu with MenuStrip and MenuItem with ToolStripMenuItem 
For me running this line:
m_SharedMem = MapViewOfFile(m_SharedFile, SECTION_MAP_READ, 0, 0, 512);

Is equal to 0x000001be0c310000. Notice it's not 8 hexes it's 16 hex chars after the 0x and you're using m_SharedMem.IntPtr32.
Therefore the System.OverflowException is because IntPtr.ToInt32() cannot handle values that are outside the range of a 32-bit integer, typical on 64-bit systems.
Instead use IntPtr.ToInt64() to handle the pointer arithmetic properly on 64-bit systems.
ps This project has some problems, like this error:

Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'lsvOutput' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.'

You'll have to invoke the UI controls on the main GUI thread from the background threads to overcome this. Also probably better running it from a different thread since it hangs the GUI and does Cross-thread operations anyway:
// Fire and forget
_ = Task.Run(() => DebugMonitor.Start());

For some reason I had to instantate the Form before running it:
var frm = new FMain();
Application.Run(frm);
// Application.Run(new FMain());


IntPtr.ToInt64() fixed the problem, but I also want to know why it doesn't throw that error on .Net Framework 4.7 but it happens with .Net core?

"Instead use IntPtr.ToInt64()" - That's equally wrong, just inconsequential (for now). The real solution is not to convert at all. You have a pointer-sized integer, and that is exactly the type that allows referencing any address, regardless of architecture. The needless ToInt32() call got there because the original author blindly transliterated C++ code to C# code, but made no attempt to understand either.

I agree with @IInspectable, I think we should know more before blindly convert ToInt32 to ToInt64. What happens if in the future it turns to ToInt128.

@123iamking The issue has nothing to do with .NET Framework vs. .NET Core. It is a corollary of changed defaults (either defaults to AnyCPU, but .NET Framework has the Prefer 32-bit toggle set). When your code executes in 32-bit, "truncating" a pointer to 32 bits is a no-op.

@IInspectable got it, so we have to check 32 or 64 first. .Net Core prefer 64 instead of 32 so it got error.

No, you don't have to check anything. Just use an IntPtr and don't butcher it. It's wide enough to hold a pointer on any architecture.

@IInspectable Thank you, I got it, we just remove ToInt32/64 entirely, the final code should be IntPtr pString = m_SharedMem + Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(int));

I'd probably keep typeof(Int32) in place of typeof(int). This is a binary protocol and the exact sizes matter, so keeping the size information in the type name makes the code easier to read.

@IInspectable Thank you, I just noticed that the answer was in your first comment (The needless ToInt32() call ) all along, If I read it more carefully, I would have the answer instantly. I was a little slow & reckless, hehe.
